# How can I access to the methods of a class when there is multiple inheritance on Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have a class that inherits from another class.

```
class Profile: UserData{
}
```

And at the same time `UserData` inherits from `UIViewController`.

The problem comes because I need that `Profile` class also inherits from `UITabBarController` and I need to access to the methods of `UserData` class from `Profile` class.

What I have tried is:

```
class Profile: UITabBarController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UserData().doStuff()
    }
}
```

but this does not work for me because I need to inherit the full class (the method only works when I use `class Profile: UserData`).

I know about protocols and I tried to inherit on the protocol the class `UserData` but it is also not allowed. I also have tried copying the methods of `UserData` class on that protocol but it gives to me the following error:

> Protocol methods may not have bodies

As, by the moment, it is impossible to do multiple inheritance, is it possible to make a workaround to use all the methods of `UserData` (as if I have inherited it) on `Profile` class which inherits at the same time from `UITabBarController`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, it is not possible. Besides, if your class need to inherit more than one class, there is a huge chance that your design is flawed.

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly you are trying to achieve (in terms of functionality / UI)? I pretty much doubt you would ever need to have a class that inherits from both `UIViewController` and `UITabBarController`...

Comment: @jcaron I need that in a `UITabBarController` will be a personal menu, that is created on `UserData`.

Comment: What do you mean by "in"? As a tab? You don't need to subclass `UITabBarController` for that, you create a regular `UITabBarController` and provide your custom `UIViewController` as one of its view controllers.

Comment: NB: you might be confusing inheritance of classes with parent-child relationships of view controllers. They are completely unrelated.

Comment: @jcaron but if I try to link my `TabBarController` with my `Profile` class, I am not able to link them.

Comment: What do you mean by "link"?

Comment: @jcaron On the right side of XCode, on `Identity inspector` section, set Class to Profile.

Comment: Why would you need to do that? Create your `UIViewController` subclass, assign it to a `UIViewController` in interface builder, and link that to the `UITabBarController` (using Ctrl-Drag from the `UITabBarController` to your customer `UIViewController` subclass).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Protocol and delegates - apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html). As you said that you tried protocol then you must have done some mistake in implementation. Otherwise this can be handle by protocol and delegates.

Refer apple documentation as i have shared in above paragraph.

You `profile` class should be delegate of your `userdata` class. and then it can access it's methods.

You car refer [Quick Guide to Swift Delegates](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/) also!